# SAS "Goal Seek" with Data Transformations

Tags: sas

I am attempting to replicate Excel's Goal Seek in SAS.
I would like to find a constant number that when added to the initial data the overall average of the data equals the target.  This gets a bit tricky when a transformation is involved.

So my three data points (var1) are 0.78, 0.8, 0.85.  The target is 0.87.
I would like to find x where AVERAGE(1/(1+EXP(-(LN(var1/(1+var1)) + x))) = 0.87

This is the code I currently have, but it gets x = 0.4803 when it should be 0.4525 (found via Excel).

```
data aa;
     input var1 target;
     datalines;
0.78 0.87
0.8 0.87
0.85 0.87
;
run;

proc model data=aa outparms=parm;
target = 1/(1+EXP(-(log(var1/(1-var1)) + x)));
fit target;
run;
```

I think this isn't working bc it doesn't include an average of all 3 data points.  I'm not sure how to do this.  Ideally I'd just be able to change the second line in the proc model node to this:

```
target = Avg(1/(1+EXP(-(log(var1/(1-var1)) + x))));
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`proc model` is primarily designed for time-series, and doesn't do well with using summary functions vertically; however, it does great when doing it horizontally. One way to resolve it would be by transposing the problem:

```
proc transpose data=aa out=aa_trans;
    by target;
    var var1;
run;

proc model data=aa_trans;
    endo x;
    exo COL1-COL3 target;

    target = mean(1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL1/(1-COL1)) + x)))
                , 1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL2/(1-COL2)) + x)))
                , 1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL3/(1-COL3)) + x))) );

    solve / out=solution solveprint ;
run;
```

We get an answer of **`0.4531398172`**. This can be checked by directly plugging in the value:

```
data _null_;
    set aa_trans;

    x = 0.4531398172;

    check = mean(1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL1/(1-COL1)) + x)))
               , 1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL2/(1-COL2)) + x)))
               , 1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL3/(1-COL3)) + x))) );

    put '*********** ' check;
run;
```

This method requires additional macro programming to generalize, and may be very computationally expensive if you have many observations to transpose.  To generalize it for any given number of columns, you could use the following macro program:

```
%macro generateEquation;
    %global eq;

    %let eq = ;

    proc sql noprint;
        select count(*)
        into :total
        from aa
        ;
    quit;

    %do i = 1 %to &total.;
        %let eq = %cmpres(&eq 1/(1+EXP(-(log(COL&i/(1-COL&i))+x))));
    %end;

    %let eq = mean(%sysfunc(tranwrd(&eq, %str( ), %str(,) ) ) );

    %put &eq;
%mend;
%generateEquation;

proc model data=aa_trans;
    endo x;
    exo COL1-COL3 target;

    target = &eq.;

    solve / out=solution solveprint ;
run;
```

Instead, you might want to reframe this problem as an optimization problem with no objective function. `proc optmodel`, if available at your site, lets you do this matrix manipulation. The resulting code is more complex and manual, but will give you a more generalized and computationally feasible result.

You will need to add two new variables and separate the target to a new dataset.

```
data aa;
     input targetid obs var1;
     datalines;
1 1 0.78
1 2 0.8
1 3 0.85
;
run;

data bb;
    input targetid target;
    datalines;
1 0.87
;
run;

proc optmodel;
    set id;
    set obs;
    set <num,num> id_obs;

    /* Constants */
    number target{id};
    number var1{id_obs};

    read data bb into id=[targetid]
        target;

    read data aa into id_obs=[targetid obs]
        var1;

    /* Parameter of interest */
    var x{id};

    /* Force the solver to seek the required goal */
    con avg {i in id}: target[i] = sum{<j,n> in id_obs: j=i} (1/(1+EXP(-(log(var1[j, n]/(1-var1[j, n])) + x[i]))) ) 
                                 / sum{<j,n> in id_obs: j=i} 1;

    /* Check if it's the equation that we want */
    expand;

    /* Solve using the non-linear programming solver with no objective */
    solve with nlp noobjective;

    /* Output */
    create data solution from [targetid] = {i in id}
        x[i];
quit;
```

`optmodel` returns a similar answer: **`0.4531395426`**, which differs by 0.0000002746 decimal places. The answers are not identical due to differing methods and optimality tolerances; however, the solution checks out.

```
proc sql;
    select Avg(1/(1+EXP(-(log(var1/(1-var1)) + 0.4531395426))))
    from aa;
quit;
```

Comment: I don't have access to optmodel, but the method using transpose works very well.  Thank you!  
  
Is there a way to generalize the proc model after the transpose to include as many columns as are in the data set rather than the specified three?

Comment: Updated with a generalized method